# MYSQL loop this code

Tags: mysql, loops

I want the following code to run with multiple end dates. those end dates must al be the first day of the month.
I can execute the code several times while changing the end date myself but thats to much work of i want montly data from 2001 until now. So my guess is I have to loop this?

Here is the code i'm using:

```
Select t4.Count, t4.Status
From(
    SELECT count(l.VoerID) as Count, l.Datum, l.Status, l.LogID
      FROM (
             SELECT k.VoerID, k.Datum, MAX(k.LogID) AS LogID
               FROM DB.LogStatus k
                Where Datum > '2001-01-01'
                and Datum < '2013-07-01'
              GROUP BY k.VoerID
           ) m
      JOIN DB.LogStatus l
        ON l.VoerID = m.VoertuigID AND l.LogID = m.LogID
    Where status in ('x',y,'z')
    Group by Status
)t4
```

Who can help?

EDIT::::: @STEPH

When I use this peace of code (1):

```
SELECT VoertID,max(LogID) as MaxLogID,Datum
          from DB.LogStatus
WHERE Datum >= '2001-01-01'
                    and Datum < '2013-07-01'
and VoerID = '50789'
GROUP BY VoerID
```

i get VoerID 50789 with the last LogID but not the corresponding date. hows that possible?

Comment: There are a number of choices, but you can put it in a shell script/batch file or use something like php.

Using some simple Unix/Linux tools (such as awk) you can even format the output nicely.

Comment: Well can i do that within Mysql or within this code. (im fairly new a this...) and how?

Comment: What are you looking to do with the data grouped by status? Would one result set that had `Month, Status, LogID*, Datum*, Count` work for you?    *These are the FIRST occuring values for these since they are not in the group by

Comment: @ steph I want to see how many VoerID there are per status and on different dates. i'll ad how the outcome should look ..

Comment: Because unless you GROUP BY a field or aggregate it, mysql will,by default, return the FIRST value for a column.  You need to do `max(Datum) as Datum` to get latest date

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, you need to manipulate your date to always return the first of the month.

In the SQL below, I have presented a moethod to do so that involves working out how many days past the begining of the month (relative to each date) there has been and substracting it.

```
    SELECT date_sub(Datum,interval day(Datum)-1 day) datum, status, count(l.VoerID) as count
    FROM DB.LogStatus l
INNER JOIN (SELECT VoerID,max(LogID) as MaxLogID 
          from DB.LogStatus
WHERE Datum >= '2001-01-01'
                    and Datum < '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY VoerID) maxl on l.VoerID=Maxl.VoerID and l.LogID=Maxl.MaxLogID

Where status in ('x','y','z')
and Datum >= '2001-01-01'
                and Datum < '2013-07-01'

GROUP BY date_sub(Datum,interval day(Datum)-1 day),status
```

Breaking down your original code:

1. Return for a given VoerID, return the FIRST Date and MAX LogID

   ```
          SELECT k.VoerID, k.Datum, MAX(k.LogID) AS LogID 
          FROM DB.LogStatus k

          Where Datum > '2001-01-01'

          and Datum < '2013-07-01'

         GROUP BY k.VoerID
   ```
2. Get all items from the log where the status is in a range and where the LogIDs match and the VoerID in the table matches the VoertuigID from the derived table (not actually present in code).  Group by log status and get FIRST Datum, FIRST LogID and the COUNT

   ```
         SELECT count(l.VoerID) as Count, l.Datum, l.Status, l.LogID
               FROM (            step1           ) m
               JOIN DB.LogStatus l
                 ON l.VoerID = m.VoertuigID AND l.LogID = m.LogID
             Where status in ('x',y,'z')
             Group by Status
   ```
3. Return Count and Status columns from 2

The revised code does:

1. Identifies last LogID for each VoerID within certain dates

   ```
    SELECT VoerID,max(LogID) as MaxLogID 
             from DB.LogStatus
   WHERE Datum >= '2001-01-01'
                       and Datum < '2013-07-01'
   GROUP BY VoerID
   ```
2. Restricts log by these max LogIDs, then filters on relevant statuses, and then counts the number of rows per status per first of month

   ```
   SELECT date_sub(Datum,interval day(Datum)-1 day) datum, status, count(l.VoerID) as count

   FROM DB.LogStatus l
   INNER JOIN ( m  ) maxl on l.VoerID=Maxl.VoerID and l.LogID=Maxl.MaxLogID
   Where status in ('x','y','z')
   and Datum >= '2001-01-01'
   and Datum < '2013-07-01'
   GROUP BY date_sub(Datum,interval day(Datum)-1 day),status
   ```

Comment: I dont get that.... I think that the part in my sql: and Datum < '2013-07-01'
should be variable based on certain set of 'firstofmonths'. so lets say for the last three years. how does your code fit into that?

Comment: I've added a where clause - the adjusted datum column brings everything to a first of the month so that you end up with a max of three rows (for each status) per month.  If you need to manipulate the month's you want to display you would adjust the WHERE clause to suit.  Again, you could do date arithmetic to make this dynamic e.g. last 3 years.

Comment: When I run hjust that code I get wrong counts. My code was designed to get the correct count. seems like i need to add the date_sub somewhere in my code.... i'm gonna take some guesses... :-)

Comment: Good luck! Also, I noticed in the status clause it was `('x',y,'z')` where I C&Pd from your code above - after correcting, that may work out a bit better, if this is a prod not example code.

Comment: cant get the datesub thing to work, get all strange outcomes, no logic...I get all low counts.. but i need per firstofmonth a total count per status... should i ad your code in a different table?

Comment: Not sure, your code is pretty hairy - there is a lot of logic in there, I've broken it down to say what it is doing at each step, you might want to make sure that what you're comparing against is doing the right thing throughout. If you're still encountering difficulties, update your Q with a sqlfiddle.com containing the table spec, some data and your queries.

Comment: first voertuigID should be VoerID. This code is not correct. i'll try to explane: I want the see for numourus dates (firsts of month) the status belonging to the last logID per VoerID (the last log before the given date) so in my code i get the count of distinct(grouped by) VoerID's based on the last LogID before the datum < 2013-07-01.

Comment: Ah ok, I have added a JOIN to the final logID for each VoerID.  It is date restricted but not status restricted - depending on whether you want the last LogID where the status was met or the last LogID you can move the status restriction to inside the JOINed query.

Comment: when i move the group by status to the inner join, the outcome gives only one status (the count seems right though)

Comment: No need to move the GROUP BY in unless you want for VoerID and status the last logID for each combo.  At this point, I would really suggest you define exactly what you are trying to achieve not how you want it displayed e.g. 'I want to know how many Voers had their final status on a given day, split by final status where I'm only interested in x,y&z' or 'I want to know how many Voer's last attained a status I'm interested in, split by day and status'

Comment: I want to know on every first of the month how many voers had status x, how many status y, how many status z. based on the last Log per voer.

Comment: Updated to include explanation